# Handling CORS between Rails API and React

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, rest, rack-cors

I'm coding a Rest API using Ruby on Rails 6, I'm testing one of the endpoint (it's a GET Request) using Postman or Curl I'm getting the expected response; when I try to use my frontend (React) I'm getting a 200 response but the data is not fetched.

These pictures are from the firefox's console:

[image: console1]

This is the data sent from the backend:

[image: console2]

but in the DOM the data is not displayed it:

[image: dom]

All right, my frontend(localhost:3005) code looks like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMeals = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/meals.json", {
        'method': 'GET',
        'mode': 'no-cors',
        'headers': {
          'Origin': 'localhost:3000',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
      });
      //https://movieserp-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/meals.json

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("The data could not be shown");
      }

      const responseData = await response.json(); 
      //el objeto se traduce a un array
      const loadedMeals = [];

      for (const key in responseData) {
        loadedMeals.push({
          id: key,
          name: responseData[key].name,
          description: responseData[key].description,
          price: responseData[key].price,
        });
      }

      //checking if the array is not null
      if (!loadedMeals.length) {
        throw new Error("No products found to display");
      } else {
        setMeals(loadedMeals);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchMeals().catch((error) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setHttpError(error.message);
    });
  }, []);
```

and this is the backend (localhost:3000) code (config/initializers/cors.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'localhost:3005', '127.0.0.1:3005'

    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

Bellow you can find the controller's source code:

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
    #get /meals
    def index
        @meals = Meal.all
        render json: @meals
    end
end
```

And finally the model:

```
class Meal < ApplicationRecord

    def as_json(options = {})
        super(:only => [:id, :name, :description, :price])
    end
    
end
```

In the browser's console (Firefox) I got status 200 and the response looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Cheese and Loroco",
        "description": "Corn made pupusa with cheese",
        "price": "1.25"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Cheese and red deans",
        "description": "Corn made pupusa with cheese and beans",
        "price": "0.65"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Pork, cheese and red beans",
        "description": "Corn made pupusa with a mix of pork,cheese and red beans",
        "price": "0.85"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Soda",
        "description": "Salvadoran soda beverages",
        "price": "0.65"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Coffee",
        "description": "High quality roasted salvadoran coffee",
        "price": "1.1"
    }
]
```

However, the data is not displayed in the DOM, in fact, the fetch object (response) is null.

My questions are:

1. I'm getting the data from the backend (it is displayed in the browser's console)
2. Why in the frontend the object (response) is null?
3. response.ok is equals to false, if I got a 200 response, why I'm not getting the data in json format to the front end?

I really will appreciate your comments or guidance about it.

thanks a lot

Comment: That is odd... can you expand the front-end code to share the code that performs the console logging, and the code that is supposed to render results to sceen? I also find it odd that you are specifying `no-cors` mode in the `fetch` call.

Comment: I would try something like changing `mode` to `cors` in your fetch call, and also adding `credentials: include` as an additional option in the fetch call

Comment: I don't think this is a CORS issue. Normally if the browser decides to cancel this request because of CORS you wouldn't even get a response back - and especially not a status code 200. It's more likely that there is something wrong with how the request is handled inside your JS than it is a CORS issue. Good luck!

Comment: @obiruby I added the complete method that handles the fetch data, on fact: before use Ruby on Rails for backend I tried with Firebase and everything works as expected

Comment: @zarathustra you right, at the end of the day I got that conclusion, it is a problem of: 1) how Rails structure the response in JSON format or 2) how JS handles the response, we'll see tomorrow

Comment: I'm no react expert but might this issue be related to the fact that the code is written in a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array? Maybe experiment with seeing how the code behaves outside of `useEffect`.

Comment: @obiruby I thought about it, although it may be useful to try a different approach than useEffect, but still I have concerns related to the backend. As a matter of fact the frontend code works like a charm when I tested with Firebase as backend

Answer (score 1):

Add GemFile: `gem 'rack-cors'`

Add application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
     origins '*'
     resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :patch, :put, :delete]
   end
end
```

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
    //path: http://localhost:3000/meals.json
    def index
        @meals = Meal.all
        respond_to do |format|
         format.html
         format.json {render json: @meals}
        end
    end
end
```

or

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
    //path: http://localhost:3000/meals
    def index
        @meals = Meal.all
        render json: @meals
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot @LihnNguyen, as a matter of fact that is exactly my code in my cors.rb (I'm using Rails 6), I think the CORS issued is solved, right now, it just a matter why I'm not fetching the data

Comment: I just update answer. Can you check again.

Comment: thanks a lot @LihnNguyen, I did all the updates needed to use respond_to but still the frontend can't fetch the data

Comment: I included how the data is sent from the backend, is that the expected JSON format? I guess so

Comment: @htamayo we can connect together ? https://www.linkedin.com/in/linh-nguyen-96919a143/ . I wanna support this issue.

Comment: thanks a lot @LihnNguyen, I will send you a request